# Why not record ASP.NET logs inside host environment.(IIS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, log4net

I hosted my asp.net site in IIS6 but it's not record log data. there are no problem in my local machine and records all logs data(Visual studio 2010). I used Log4Net dll. Please help me. this is my web config file data.

```
 <log4net>
  <root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="InfoLogAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="TraceLogAppender" />
</root>

<logger name="InfoLogger" additivity="false">
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="InfoLogAppender" />
</logger>

<logger name="ErrorLogger" additivity="false">
  <level value="ERROR" />
  <appender-ref ref="ErrorLogAppender" />
</logger>

 <logger name="TraceLogger" additivity="false">
  <level value="INFO"/>
  <appender-ref ref="TraceLogAppender"/>
</logger>
<appender name="TraceLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="Logs\\TraceLog.txt" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <param name="maximumFileSize" value="1024KB" />
  <param name="maxSizeRollBackups" value="20" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="Header" value="[START]\r\n" />
    <param name="Footer" value="[END]\r\n" />
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="InfoLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="Logs\\InfoLog.txt" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <param name="maximumFileSize" value="1024KB" />
  <param name="maxSizeRollBackups" value="20" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="Header" value="[START]\r\n" />
    <param name="Footer" value="[END]\r\n" />
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="ErrorLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="Logs\\ErrorLog.txt" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <param name="maximumFileSize" value="1024KB" />
  <param name="maxSizeRollBackups" value="20" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="Header" value="[START]\r\n" />
    <param name="Footer" value="[END]\r\n" />
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>

</log4net>
```

Comment: Try to change the File path  to something like .\Logs\log.txt

Comment: Sounds like the account used in the hosting environment does not have the required permissions to create and write to the file.